# Typescript - Default parameters on class with interface

Tags: interface, arguments, typescript, default-value

I have a scenario where I have an interface which has a method like so:

```
interface SomeInterface
{
   SomeMethod(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: boolean);
}
```

And a class like so:

```
class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface
{
   public SomeMethod(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: boolean = true){...}
}
```

Now the problem is I cannot seem to tell the interface that the 3rd option should be optional or have a default value, as if I try to tell the interface there is a default value I get the error:

`TS2174: Default arguments are not allowed in an overload parameter.`

If I omit the default from the interface and invokes it like so:

```
var myObject = new SomeImplementation();
myObject.SomeMethod("foo", "bar");
```

It complains that the parameters do not match any override. So is there a way to be able to have default values for parameters and inherit from an interface, I dont mind if the interface has to have the value as default too as it is always going to be an optional argument.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can define the parameter to be optional with `?`:

```
interface SomeInterface {
     SomeMethod(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3?: boolean);
}
```

Comment: oh I thought this was removed in favor of the default value in one of the recent versions. So I am able to use the optional argument in the interface and default value argument in the class?

Comment: You can still use optional arguments without defaults anywhere. The only disallowed thing is the redundant syntax `x ?= 4` -- you can either have the `?` or the default value.

Comment: And beware that if you call `SomeMethod('foo','bar')` the `arg3` parameter will be `undefined`, and not `null`.

Comment: And also, if you have a optional argument, all following arguments must also be optional. So `arg4: boolean` is not allowed.